# PXSSH truncates command sent to remote server

Tags: python, pxssh

I have a python application that sends a wide variety of unix commands using [pxssh](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) to a remote server using the versions below.

Version info:
Python  - 3.6.5
pexpect - 4.2.1

On one particular server one of our commands failed to execute because the command was truncated by (we think) pxssh.

We are not able to reproduce the issue in our dev/test envs, and cannot test in a PROD system for obvious reasons.  This is also the first time this has happened on any of our systems.  A similar command (the same in all but 1 character - different date), successfully executed immediately before this command failed.

In the log snippet below you can see the path of the scp target is truncated by 1 character.  Any ideas on what to look at for why this occurred?

Code snippet showing creation and use of pxssh object:

```py
self.connection = pxssh.pxssh(encoding='utf-8', echo=True,
                              timeout=None, 
                              options={"StrictHostKeyChecking": "no"})
...
self.logger.info(self.log_header + 'The command is: ' + command)
self.connection.sendline(command)
self.connection.prompt()
log = self.connection.before
...
self.logger.info(self.log_header + log)
self.logger.info(self.log_header + 'Executed command: ' + command)
```

Here is the sanitized log output showing the error:

```
[INFO] The command is: scp -p *20190717* <server>:/path/to/target/location/
[INFO] Command output: [YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
/path/to/target/locatio: No such file or directory
```

As you can see above, the `n/` was truncated from `/path/to/target/location/`

Here is what success looks like (again sanitized):

```
[INFO] The command is: scp -p *20190718* <server>:/path/to/target/location/
[INFO] Command output: [YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
File1                        100%   53MB  16.0MB/s   00:03
File2                        100%   20MB  16.2MB/s   00:01
[INFO] Executed command: scp -p *20190718* <server>:/path/to/target/location/
```